# Implement interface for COM DLL class?

Tags: vb.net, dll, com

I am creating a COM DLL within VB.net which is replacing an older VB6 dll.

When creating COM exposed classes, what is the benefit (if any) to implementing an interface within VB.net?

These classes could be used within other .net projects in the future.  Assuming they are used within other .net projects in the future, I could create an interface at that time, so the question is what benefit, if any, would the interface provide today?

Comment: Early binding (e.g. .NET, C++, VB6), efficiency (no method or property dispatching by name), object browsing (e.g. Visual Studio, VBA in Office), type library inspection (OleView.exe), to name a few.

Comment: Interfaces are core to the way COM works, that's what the client program uses to talk to your component.  If you want guaranteed binary compatibility with the legacy component then use its interface declarations, add a reference to the component and write classes that implement its interfaces.  If this is not intended to be a drop-in replacement for the legacy component but is only used from .NET programs then the COM considerations are not relevant.

Comment: Thank you both for answering my question.  When adding a COM Class via the Add menu no interface is defined.  It sounds like an individual interface needs to be defined.